# Is it possible to constrain a type parameter not to have a property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Can I write a function

```
const f = <T extends ???>(x: T) => ...
```

such that the calls to it compile if and only if `T` doesn't have a particular property? My specific usecase is [this function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hoc/#withapollocomponent):

```
export declare function withApollo<TProps, TResult = any>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<WithApolloClient<Omit<TProps, "client">>>, operationOptions?: OperationOption<TProps, TResult>): React.ComponentClass<Omit<TProps, "client">>;
```

I found type inference works badly with it and requires always supplying an explicit type parameter in our codebase. If I could specify that `T` doesn't have `"client"`, I could provide a better wrapper.